# How to finish Butt joint and corner bead within 5"?

Tags: drywall, joints, corner-bead

[image]

I created pass through door between my kitchen and dining room. I am done screwing sheetrock to cover framing. I need to finish this job with drywall tapping and corner bead installation.

Now as you can see in picture, butt joint and edge of door (where vinyl corner bead will be installed) is just 5" away from each other.  How many coats of mud should I apply and in which sequence ? Can my 3rd/4th coat for butt joint be applied during corner bead coat ?  I am assuming that my corner bead coat will be wide around 6" anyway to blend in corner beads.

Comment: I think you should consider using metal corner bead rather than vinyl, for an oft-used pass-thru doorway; more resistant to inevitable collisions with humans and the stuff they carry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no change to your process here. I prefer to tape the butt joints so I can then skim out the bead without interference. This would be true whether the butt joint was near the bead or not.

I don't think of taping in terms of "coats". You have a series of steps that leads to an outcome--specifically a flat surface. This isn't paint, and the thickness of your compound applications should be the minimum necessary to achieve that flat surface, not some number of coats.

I suggest that you picture a cross-section of this situation. It's a bead on one end, which protrudes above the plane of the drywall sheets. You then have this butt joint, which would lay below a straight line between the bead and a point on the wall say 24" away, where the taper will end. Since the butt joint is below that plane, it should be completed first.

Drywall is an art, and unless you're pressed for time, just do one thing at a time, let it dry, then another. You'll have less frustration and use less mud (which should always be a goal--sanding should be only to polish the final surface, not to re-shape anything).

Answer (score 3):

Other than the first coat being forced into the joints, this is not two separate operations. You're going to be looking for one joint from the corner bead to the feather-edge of the butt-joint.

As for number of coats, as many as it takes, remembering not to waste time fussing over them - get mud on, let dry, sand or scrape for high spots, more mud for low spots, until there are no more low spots. There is no fixed number.